# Equivalent definitions for Noetherian rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there a straight forward proof of the equivalence of the two definitions of stationary ascending chain of ideals and the existence of a maximal element in any non-empty family of ideals in a ring $R$?

I mean, without using the contrapositive.

Comment: What exactly do you find not straightforward about the usual proof?

Answer (score 5):

If every family of ideals has a maximal element, the ascending chain condition is trivially satisfied. On the other hand, if the ascending chain condition is satisfied, a basic use of Zorn's lemma yields immediatly the other condition.